# Making HTML recognize user input tags

Tags: javascript, html, user-input, html-escape-characters, word-processor

Hey all you awesome smart people,

I need some help with user input. I am creating a basic word processor, and I need to make a certain selected area bold. The user will highlight the area with the mouse and press the button. The computer will then replace their highlighted text with `<b>+originaltext+</b>`, supposedly making it bold. Problem is, the computer is turning those open and closed carrots into `&lt;` and therefore preventing it from doing its job.

How can I force the computer to hand it over as real bold tags?

Here is what I am doing basically:

```
function replaceSelectedText() {
var sel, range, txtstuff;
if (window.getSelection) {
    txtstuff = '<b>'+window.getSelection()+'</b>'
    sel = window.getSelection();
    alert(txtstuff, sel);
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(txtstuff));
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.text = txtstuff;
}
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

**UPDATE:** This is in an editable div.

Comment: Can you share the HTML as well?

Comment: You are using `document.createTextNode`, which creates text, not elements. You need to use `document.createElement('b')` and set its `innerHTML` property.

Comment: @Cuberto, How would I go about implementing that in the code I shared?

Comment: after `range.deleteContents()`, do `var b = document.createElement('b'); b.innerHTML = txtstuff;` and then insert the `b` with `range.insertNode(b);`

Comment: You really rock @bvx89 I was working on that for so long... I wish you could give people points on this thing!!

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your reply. You can help me the next time I'm stuck ;)

Comment: @bvx89 Why not add your comments as an answer so we can vote it up and Isiah can give you those points.

Comment: @pwdst All right, answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
function replaceSelectedText() {
    var sel, range, txtstuff;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        txtstuff = '<b>'+window.getSelection()+'</b>'
        sel = window.getSelection();
        alert(txtstuff, sel);
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            var b = document.createElement('b');
            b.innerHTML = txtstuff;
            range.insertNode(b);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.text = txtstuff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on document.execCommand
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

The syntax in your case would be:

```
document.execCommand('bold');
```

Even though it's Mozilla's documentation this is very cross-browser.  It also doesn't rely on possibly buggy cursor selection.